# Angular Custom Directive Data Binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form that I am trying to turn the date picker object into a directive. I am able to get the data into the input, but it's not binding the data with the scope variable that is passed to it. Here's my code.

View:

```
<ng-date-picker id-attr="lastRedemptionDate" ng-model="spr.lastRedemptionDate"></ng-date-picker>
```

Directive:

```
myApp.directive('ngDatePicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        templateUrl: 'assets/angular/directives/datePicker.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            objID: '@idAttr',
            personName: "=ngModel"
        },
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs, controllerInstance) {
            $scope.$apply($scope.method());

            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                format: 'm/d/yyyy',
                autoclose: true
            });

            console.log($scope);
        }
    }
})
```

Directive Template:

```
<div class='input-group input-append date'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control datepicker" id="{{ objID }}" value="{{ personName }}" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ngModel directive to bind model to input instead of value attribute:

```
<div class='input-group input-append date'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control datepicker" ng-model="personName" id="{{ objID }}" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```